# Python как использовать in вместе с цифрами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как понять содержит ли лист подлистов:[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]] лист [0,1,3,2] ?

Comment: Что Вы пытались сделать самостоятельно? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6]]
b = [0,1,3,2]

print(b in a)
```

Comment: Но ведь a содержит b но при этом результат все равно false

Comment: где у вас в массиве 'a' есть список [0,1,3,2]? какой элемент по счету?